# How can I extract parallel columns from a matrix to form an array

Tags: arrays, r

I modified some tables into an excel file and converted it into a .csv to practice some basic R data selection. When trying to create an array from matrices that I've made it only outputs the class and not the original value. What can I change in my code?

```
> dat1
   NumberEvents percentTotal
1        254763        100.0
2        183441         72.0
3        183190         71.9
4        137763         54.1
5        118604         46.6
6         46464         18.2
7         41544         16.3
8         41340         16.2
9         15533          6.1
10        37140         14.6
11        28390         11.1
12        12253          4.8
13            4          0.0
```

dat2 and dat3 are similar matrices (same dimensions, but different values).

```
> cleanest <- array(c(dat1, dat2, dat3), c(13, 2, 3))
> cleanest
, , 1

      [,1]       [,2]      
 [1,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
 [2,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
 [3,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
 [4,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
 [5,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
 [6,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
 [7,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
 [8,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
 [9,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
[10,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
[11,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
[12,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
[13,] Numeric,13 Numeric,13
```

The other two dimensions give the same result of  "numeric, 13" as well.

```
> is.array(cleanest)
[1] TRUE
>
```

The output I expected was the original values, but to be an array format for subsequent analysis.

What can I fix?

Comment: `dat1` seems to be a dataframe. Do you need `array(unlist(c(dat1, dat2, dat3)), c(13, 2, 3))` ?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for your help!